# Where should we update the model in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I'm learning MVVM. I was reading a sample code [https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#3) about MVVM. There is a Book entity and it has updated from an activity like the following:

```
Book book = new Book();
book.setName(x);
```

But I think we should not have a model instance in the View layer and we should do this in ViewModel, not in View. Something like the following code in the View:

```
MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
viewModel.setBookName(x);
```

My question is can we instantiate an entity in View and what is the right way to do this?

Comment: You're right that `View` shouldn't directly coordinate with `Models` & that's why `ViewModel` comes in picture. *(Although syntax you've written is not suggested way of initiating ViewModels)*

Comment: By instatntiating the entity, 
What's your actual need?

Comment: You should update model class in View model only.

Answer (score 0):

You should update model class in View Model only..

Create an Interface for an Activity **IContract.java**

```
 public interface IContract {

    interface View 
    {
        public void displayModelData();

    }

    interface ViewModel 
    {
        public Book setModelData();
        public Book getModelData();
    }
}
```

> - Then implement View interface in Activity class and View Model    Interface in ViewModel class..
> - Now create an reference ViewModel object in Activity class.
> - where we can pass the data from ViewModel to View using that object

Activity class **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity implements IContract.View {
    private IContract.ViewModel viewModel; //create a instance for ViewModel object

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.viewModel = new MainActivityViewModel(getApplicationContext());// object initialisation


        @overide
        public void displayModelData()
        {
            viewModel.setModelData(); // update model class
            Book obj = viewModel.getModelData();// this will get book object from viewModel class.
            Toast(obj.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.java**

```
  public class MainActivityViewModelimplements IContract.ViewModel

{
    Context context;
    Book book;

    public void MainActivityViewModel (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void setModelData ()
    {
        book = new Book(); // update model class.
        book.setName(x);
    }

    @Override
    public Book getModelData ()
    {
        return book; //return the object to the view
    }

}
```